# Monitor kafka with Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, prometheus

I have followed the below steps to monitor kafka with Prometheus and Grafana.

**jmx port not get opened**

```
wget http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.10.1.0/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.tgz
tar -xzf kafka_*.tgz
cd kafka_*

wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.6/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.6.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/master/example_configs/kafka-0-8-2.yml

./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
KAFKA_OPTS="$KAFKA_OPTS -javaagent:$PWD/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.6.jar=7071:$PWD/kafka-0-8-2.yml" 
 ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
```

Then  i have the checked with `curl http://localhost:7071/metrics` in the terminal

it reports `curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:7071; Connection refused`

Currently i have opened all my ports to my network in the server.

while i m checking with `netstat -tupln | grep LISTEN`
port number 7071 was not listed in the output

The below is the kafka directory's contents:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    4096 Aug 23 12:22 bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Oct 15  2016 config
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   20356 Aug 21 10:50 hs_err_pid1496.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   19432 Aug 21 10:55 hs_err_pid2447.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1225418 Feb  5  2016 jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.6.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    2824 Aug 21 10:48 kafka-0-8-2.yml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Aug 21 10:48 libs
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   28824 Oct  5  2016 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Oct 11 15:05 logs
-rw-------. 1 root root    8453 Aug 23 12:08 nohup.out
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     336 Oct  5  2016 NOTICE
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root      46 Oct 15  2016 site-docs
```

kafka is running in 2181 port and zookeeper is also running

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind opening up the jmx port, you can also do it like this:

```
export JMX_PORT=9999
export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999'
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
java -jar jmx_prometheus_httpserver-0.10-jar-with-dependencies.jar 9300 kafka-0-8-2.yaml &
```

The `jar-with-dependencies` you build from the [source](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/releases) with `mvn package`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when setting KAFKA_OPTS environment variable in the bash. The worse situation is when you add the environment variable to ~/.profile file. The problem with this approach is that the KAFKA_OPTS is used for both  kafka-server-start.sh and zookeeper-server-start.sh so when you start Zookeeper, port 7071 will be used by Zookeeper for exporting metrics. Then, when you run Kafka you will receive the "7071 port is in use error".

I solved the problem by setting the environment at systemd service file. I described it at [my article](https://medium.com/@mousavi310/monitor-apache-kafka-using-grafana-and-prometheus-873c7a0005e2) last week:

```
[Unit]
...
[Service]
...
Restart=no
 Environment=KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/home/morteza/myworks/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.9.jar=7071:/home/morteza/myworks/kafka-2_0_0.yml
[Install]
...
```